ラズパイにnfcpyをインストールしたい
大学で、ラズパイとカードリーダーを使って研究をしているものです。
こちらの下記のサイトを参考に進めようとしていたところ、序盤のnfcpyをインストールするところで行き詰ってしまいました。
Raspberry Piを使って学生証から学籍番号を読み取ろう：
https://qiita.com/Requin/items/206ce5fdf6b4644fd149
これらのサイトの通りにnfcpyを入れようとすると、以下のエラーが出ます。
error: externally-managed-environment

調べると、仮想環境を作ってそこに入れてね(？)ということらしいので、
python -m venv　mypy
source ./mypy/bin/activate

で、仮想環境を作って同じく、インストールを試みましたが、まったく同じエラーが出てしまいます。
(mypy)がターミナルの前についているので、仮想環境を作ることはできていると思います。

素人質問で恐縮ですが、どなたかご教示いただきたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。
追記
コメントしてくださった方の通りにしたところ、仮想環境でnfcpyを入れることができましたが、参考サイトの「PaSoRiを認識させる」の手順でまた詰まってしまいました。
下記コマンドを実行したところ
$ python -m nfc
実行できなかったので、サイトに記載された下記コマンドを試しました。
$ sudo sh -c 'echo SUBSYSTEM==\"usb\", `ACTION==\"add\", ATTRS{idVendor}==\"054c\", ATTRS{idProduct}==\"06c3\", GROUP=\"plugdev\" >> /etc/udev/rules.d/nfcdev.rules'

こちらのサイトでは、この処理を行えば、エラー文が、port100に関するものに変わっているのですが、私が実行したところ、エラー文に変化はなく、後述されているport100の起動をやめさせるコマンドもできませんでした。

私のコーディングミスであればよいのですが、文字や空白を確認し、何度も書き直しています。
重ね重ねの質問で恐縮ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

仮想環境をアクティブにした後、pip の前に sudo を付けて実行しているのが余計な気がします。

「何かエラーが表示される」で終わらず、翻訳にかけてでも何が書かれているかを読んでみてください。試している内容においてはかなり詳細なヒントが表示されている方だと思います。 / nfcdev.rules にルールを追加した後、sudo udevadm control -R コマンドを実行してみてください。
